# Printing hex numbers

Tags: java, hex

I  want to write a program which prints a hex number when an integer between 0 and 100 is given as an input. What is wrong with my code?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, p, q;
        n = input.nextInt();
        p = n / 16;
        q = n % 16;
        if (q == 10)
            System.out.println(p + "" + "a");
        else if (q == 11)
            System.out.println(p + "" + "b");
        else if (q == 12)
            System.out.println(p + "" + "c");
        else if (q == 13)
            System.out.println(p + "" + "d");
        else if (q == 14)
            System.out.println(p + "" + "e");
        else if (q == 15)
            System.out.println(p + "" + "f");
        else if (p == 0)
            System.out.println(q);
        else
            System.out.println(p + "" + q);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run your code and test it with `23` and `78` as input I get `17` and `4e` respectively as results, which is correct, isn't it? Why do you think there's something wrong? Can you provide an example and describe the expected and actual output?

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with my code?

The answer is: Nothing. Your code produces correct output for each input *integer between 0 and 100*.

Comment: Actually this was one of the questions of my java test. I couldn't find an error as an answer. Guess there was some kind of mistake.